# how to change driver properties language in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, language

My laptop was in the Polish language originally. I have changed everywhere i could.

I installed the correct driver from lenovo website for my machine, but the properties are in Polish, and i need to change some values there, but i dont understand anything. How can i change that language to English? It should be possible, as the drivers were downloaded from international website, it is just some setting on my laptop that makes those settings show in Polish.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Did you try the steps mentioned in this post to change the langauge? You need to do it for your account and the system account. https://www.windowscentral.com/how-properly-change-system-default-language-windows-10

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I followed that guide and it did not solve the problem. Driver settings still in the Polish language. But everywhere in settings, there is the English language.